# Limit of a sequence in $l^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I am trying to understand the $l^p$ space and what it means for a sequence to converge in it.
I am making an example of my own to see how the norm-converges works, so it maybe wrong etc.

---

let $p\geq2 $ and take $x_n=(ξ_{nk})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n^2},\frac{1}{n^3},..., \frac{1}{n^k},...)$

then $|| x_n||=\bigg(\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}|ξ_{nk}|^p \bigg)^{1/p}=\bigg(\zeta (kp) \bigg)^{1/p}=\bigg(\frac{1}{n^p}+\frac{1}{n^{2p}} +\frac{1}{n^{3p}}+... \bigg)^{1/p}$

Letting $n\rightarrow \infty$,  $|| x_n|| \rightarrow0$ meanig $||x_n-x||<ε $ where $x=(0,0,...)$
is my reasoning correct ? My professor doesn't explain much, I am a bit confused.
If I am wrong, can someone explain how to think about this.

Comment: Your example is fine. It suffices $p\ge 1.$ The norm $\|x_n\|_p$  can be calculated explicitly as you need to sum up a geometric progression. So the norm is equal $(n^p-1)^{-1/p}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc is right. You can not just pull the $\lim_n$ into the sum, since the sum is infinite. You have to find a closed form (by geometric series) and then calculate the limit. But your norm is correct.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc correct, but the limit still goes to zero, the sum is from $k=1$.   But now I have another question, what would mean if $||x_n||\rightarrow 5$ for example ? as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @lupus nox When the limit of norms tends to $0$ then $x_n$ tends to $0.$  When the norms tend to $5$ no conclusion can be derived.